# How to label articles as fact checks for Google News to pick them up as such?

Tags: google, schema.org, google-news

Today, Google is in the news for adding 'Fact check' to some articles in Google News. Google has [a blog post](https://blog.google/topics/journalism-news/labeling-fact-check-articles-google-news/) about it, but the only reference to how to set this up yourself is to [a page on schema.org](http://pending.schema.org/ClaimReview) that doesn't seem to tell me how to actually deploy this.

So, how do I set up a HTML page to be recognised by Google News as a 'Fact check'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the linked schema.org page firstly you see that the ClaimReview schema is pending which means that it may be up for change as it develops and they are still finalising examples but at the bottom it provides an example json-ld block which can be embedded in your page head.

The page also provides a description of what each tag means which is a little beyond the scope of this question and answer but basically all you have to do is add the script block to the head of your page and set the appropriate data is the json and then when Google indexes the page it will detect it. Functionally it is similar to adding OpenGraph data to the head of a page but rather than adding it all as separate meta tags the ClaimReview schema opts at the present time to do it as a single json-ld block.

Comment: Thanks. I did see the example, and noticed that not only does itself claim it's incomplete, but also that I was not clear on the json-ld block. Thanks for pointing out I only need to include this in my page head. I now also understand that the 'sub properties' (of 'reviewRating', for example), are defined in other documents (for example http://pending.schema.org/Rating).